# encryption function in c

Tags: c, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRUMv.png)so i need to write a program that scans words and then encrypts them with a given key (the key is in main).
the output should consist of the encrypted words (the encryption is using the key with the ASCII value of the letter in the word so lets say we have the word BOOK then the first letter will be switched to the key in the 65 place). I need to scan the words given by user in to strings and save the pointers to these strings to an array char *words. then i encrypt them and print them as following:

> `words[0][0-n]\n` ('n' is the length of the word=the same length as original but encr)
>       `words[1][0-k]\n` ('k' is the length of the word=the same length as original but encr)

.
.
.
im new to programming and having trouble with these strings.. help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_SIZE 256



char encrypt_char(unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE], char ch);
int read_words(char* words[], int size, int max_str_len);
void encrypt_words(char* words[], int num_words, unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE]);




   int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D',
        'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M'};

    char* words[1000];      //the words must bee a 2D array beacause its a string array .
    int num_words=read_words(words,1000,100);
    printf("number of words =%d",num_words);/////check
    encrypt_words(words,num_words,key);
    while (words[i][j]!=0)
    {
        printf("%c",words[i][j]);
        i++,j++;
    }
    return 0;
}






char encrypt_char(unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE], char ch)
{
    int temp=ch;
    return key[temp];
}





int read_words(char* words[], int size, int max_str_len)
{
    printf("in the read words func\n"); ///check
    int i=0,words_count=0;
    char* temp=malloc((max_str_len+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failure\n");
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("passed the fail test\n"); ////check
    while ( scanf("%s",temp)==1&&words_count<size)
    {
        printf("in the while \n");
        int length=strlen(temp);
        char* the_word=malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(the_word, temp);
        words[i]=(char*)the_word;
        i++;
        words_count++;
        printf("the i=%d          words count=%d          words[%d]=%s    \n",i,words_count,i,&words[i]);/////////check
    }
    printf("WORDS COUNT IS=%d\n",words_count);
return words_count;

}


void encrypt_words(char* words[], int num_words, unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    while (words[i][j]!=0&&i<num_words)
    {
        char temp=words[i][j];
        words[i][j]=encrypt_char(key,temp);
        i++,j++;
    }
}
```

compiler messege:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in hw4q2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -Werror -pedantic -ansi -W -O -g -pedantic-errors -std=c99  -c "C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\C projects\hw4q2\hw4q2.c" -o obj\Debug\hw4q2.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o hw4q2.exe obj\Debug\hw4q2.o   
Output file is hw4q2.exe with size 73.25 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what kind of problem you have.

Comment: Please be more specific than "having trouble with these strings". What specifically is the problem? What did you discover when you tried debugging the problem?

Comment: sorry , the problem is that it crashes :( it seems to get till the scans and prints the number of words given but then it does not get in the encryption i guess. i work on codeblocks and it compiles..

Comment: But does it compile ***without warnings?*** " 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 4 has type 'char **' ". That is at the line you marked with `/////////check`. Also 11 lines down warns " '!=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *' ".

Comment: yes it compiles without a warning. I have tryed putting these prints in the crossroads to see where the function got and it crashes after it prints me how many words there are..

Comment: Off topic: Never ever do `scanf("%s",temp)==` It invites for buffer overflow. Use `fgets` instead

Comment: Please **enable compiler warnings** there at least 2.

Comment: I  have added a picture of what the compiler is providing me

Comment: Strongly recommend to _not_ post pictures of text.  Add the text to your post.

Comment: Could you post a) the input that you give and b) what the program prints before it crashes

Comment: the input is :ANTON (enter) LORA (enter) MICHAEL (enter) TOMATO (enter) ctr+z (enter).
and i get the print of how many words i have and then i have a windows pop up messege that says that the program crashed.

Comment: I am aware that the print of the words is unfinished but I cant even get till there. im sorry if something is unclear here its my first time asking here.. thank you.

Comment: Better to edit your question so the information is all in one place, thank you. Please find out how to enable compiler warnings - consider them to be errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
while (words[i][j]!=0)
{
    printf("%c",words[i][j]);
    i++,j++;
}
```

Here you increment both `i` and `j` at the same time. So you both jump to the next letter and to the next string in one step. That will fail if you jump beyond the string termination.

Try this instead:

```
for (i=0; i<num_words; ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n",words[i]);
}
```

Similar problem is here:

```
void encrypt_words(char* words[], int num_words, unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    while (words[i][j]!=0&&i<num_words)
    {
        char temp=words[i][j];
        words[i][j]=encrypt_char(key,temp);

        i++,j++;   // Ups...
    }
}
```

You need to finish one string first (i.e. only increment `j`) and then move to the next string (i.e. increment `i`).

Something like:

```
void encrypt_words(char* words[], int num_words, unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (i=0; i<num_words; ++i)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (words[i][j]!=0)
        {
            char temp=words[i][j];
            words[i][j]=encrypt_char(key,temp);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you I will try that now!

Comment: @אנטוןקנרסקי - See here http://ideone.com/8OPkCa

Comment: Thank you so much it works now !!! again, sorry if my question was not clear enough and thank you for your help !